# Microsoft Graph PowerShell - Getting MFA Phone Number for All Users

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to write a script that will get all user MFA phone numbers using Graph modules. I am able to get the phone numbers to show but I'm curious as to how I can get the UPN from MGUser in the output?

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Signins
Connect-Graph -Scopes UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All
Select-MgProfile -Name v1.0

$mgUsers = Get-MgUser -All:$true | Select UserPrincipalName

foreach ($user in $mgUsers) {
    Get-MgUserAuthenticationPhoneMethod -UserId $user.UserPrincipalName | Select ID,PhoneNumber,PhoneType
    }
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `Select-Object ID, @{Name = 'UPN'; Expression = {$user.UserPrincipalName}}, PhoneNumber, PhoneType` perhaps?

Comment: This actually worked like a charm!! Thank you so much. For my own knowledge, what is this called? Specifically the @{ Name = ; Expression = {}}

Comment: That is what is called a calculated property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could use a [calculated property with `Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3):

```
Get-MgUser -All:$true -PipelineVariable user | ForEach-Object {
    Get-MgUserAuthenticationPhoneMethod -UserId $user.UserPrincipalName |
        Select-Object @{ N='UserPrincipalName'; E={ $user.UserPrincipalName }}, ID, PhoneNumber, PhoneType
}
```